# Python- Selecting a row to manipulate from an image created

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and I'm working on a code. One part of it is:

```
a=3
def tictactoe(a):
    for x in range(0,a):
        print (("- "*a))
    z=tictactoe(a)
    print(z)
```

which prints out:

```
 - - -
 - - -
 - - -
```

I would like to select a row from the image and overwrite to become, say, `- * -` instead of `- - -`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat confused: there is no data structure in your code, with rows to be "selected". But there could be!

First, create a 3x3 board, as a `list` of `list`s:

```
board = []
for x in xrange(3):
    board.append(['-']*3)
```

**Note**: If you are using Python 2.X,  `xrange` is more memory-efficient than `range`, since `xrange` doesn't generate an actual `list` to iterate over. For such a small count, the difference is negligible.

Now board is a `list` of length 3, where each element is another `list` of 3 strings `'-'`:

```
[['-','-','-'],    # <-- board[0]
 ['-','-','-'],    # <-- board[1]
 ['-','-','-']]    # <-- board[2]
```

To print the board, you could do something like this:

```
for row in board:
    print ' '.join(row)
```

**Note**: `my_string.join(my_list)` will concatenate all strings in `my_list`, separated by `my_string`.

The second row of `board` is `board[1]`, and the second element of the second row of `board` is `board[1][1]`.

So, to set the center element to `'*'`, you can:

```
board[1][1] = '*'
```

Comment: FYI, in Python 3, I'm pretty sure `range` is an iterator (the equivalent of `xrange`).

Answer (score 0):

just another approach

```
def write(board, char, row, column):
    """write char on board, row and column
    are indexed with base 1
    """
    row -= 1
    column = 2*(column - 1)
    board[row] = board[row][:column] + char + board[row][column + 1:]
    return board

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print row

if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = 3
    board = [ "- " * size for _ in range(size)]
    board = write(board,'x',1,3)
    print_board(board)
    print ''
    board = write(board,'o',1,1)
    print_board(board)
```